# How to label a partition in Linux?

Tags: command-line, partition

It is easy to find that ext2 filesystem labels can be set with **tune2fs** and **e2label**. GParted GUI offers to give partition labels when creating partitions of any type, but not to change the label of an existing partition.

I am only interested in MBR partitions (not GPT) and preferably console tools. In particular, I am using the JFS filesystem. Can I give it a label to be used in /etc/fstab ? Human-readable label, not the GUID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the description of an [MBR partition table entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#PTE) with the description of a [GPT/GUID partition entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries_(LBA_2-33)). You'll see that while the GPT/GUID partition has dedicated locations to have both an "unique partition GUID" and a "partition name", there none of those available for MBR. So you just can't do this on MBR, it's available only for GPT.

There's still an unique 32bits identifier *for the whole MBR* (at position 0x1B8) that might be usable, along with the partition number. It can be changed using [fdisk](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/fdisk.8.en.html)'s expert options:

```
# fdisk /dev/ram0
[...]
Command (m for help): x

Expert command (m for help): i

Enter the new disk identifier: 0xdf201070

Disk identifier changed from 0xdeadbeaf to 0xdf201070.

Expert command (m for help): r

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

What you should probably use, like with tune2fs for ext2, is [jfs_tune](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/jfsutils/jfs_tune.8.en.html) to label the *filesystem*. For example:

```
# jfs_tune -L mylabel /dev/ram0p1
jfs_tune version 1.1.15, 04-Mar-2011
Volume label updated successfully.
# blkid |grep ram0
/dev/ram0: PTUUID="df201070" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/ram0p1: LABEL="mylabel" UUID="e1805bac-44fb-4f4e-860b-64a1d303400f" TYPE="jfs" PARTUUID="df201070-01"
```

All "variables" output by blkid are probably usable in `/etc/fstab`, you should do tests.

Comment: jfs_tune is the proper solution, but, unfortunately I have to unmount / to use it, i.e. reboot from another disk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gdisk`:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
```

Use the `c` command to change a partition's name, and the `w` command to save your changes.

(Surely there's a command-line option for this though! Would love to be enlightened).

Comment: gdisk would convert my MBR into GPT, wich I do not want.